# how to insert a while loop in a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

I am trying to insert a while loop in a function called myFunction.
When you click on the button it should display the array result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button id="btn">Click Me!</button>

<p id="i"><strong>this</strong> represents:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
<script>

  function myFunction () {
let i = 0;
while(i<5){
    document.write(i  + '<br/>');
    i++;
}
}

var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", myFunction());


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First off, my function is missing its parentheses. Secondly, was() isn't declared and instead should have myFunction.

Comment: - line: "function myFunction {"
edit to "function was () {"

And, i think you want use document.getElementById("demo").innerHtml, not document.write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <button id="btn">Click Me!</button>

    <p id="i"><strong>this</strong> represents:</p>

    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        console.log(1)
        let i = 0;
        while (i < 5) {
          document.write(i + '<br/>');
          i++;
        }
      }

      var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
      btn.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

There were a few minor bugs to correct, e.g. `was()` should likely be `myFunction` and the definition of `myFunction` needed brackets `()` after the function name.

Comment: Thanks i was in a hurry to post and i missed out replacing the "was" with "myFunction"

Comment: So when calling a function in add eventlistener I should exclude the ()?
btn.addEventListener("click", myFunction());

Comment: It depends, if all you want to do is call the function without passing any arguments, you can do `btn.addEventListener("click", myFunction);`. If you need to do more than that, you can do it like this `btn.addEventListener("click", function() { /* do stuff */ myFunction(); anotherFunction(myArg); });` Try for yourself and see what works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing () after myFunction:

```
  function myFunction() {
let i = 0;
while(i<5){
    document.write(i  + '<br/>');
    i++;
}
}
```

are you sure you want to use `document.write` and not `console.log(i)` ?